# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null in ionic reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, ionic3

i am working in an ionic project . when using angular reactive form custom validation.It is throwing an Uncaught 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

```
     this.signup = this.formBuilder.group({
          name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, ValidateName])],
          email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, ValidateEmail])],
          mobile: [
            '',
            Validators.compose([
              Validators.required,
              Validators.minLength(10),
              Validators.maxLength(15),
              ValidateMobile
            ])
          ],
          password: [
            '2',
            Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])
          ],
          cpassword: [
            '1',
            Validators.compose([
              Validators.required,
              Validators.minLength(6),
              passwordValidat.bind(this)
            ])
          ]
        });
      }

   passwordValidat(control: AbstractControl) {
    if (control.get('password').value === control.get('cpassword').value) {
      return { invalid: true };
    }
    return { validUrl: true };
  }
```

when i'm trying to run this code getting error like this

> core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'value' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'value'
>   of null
>       at SignupPage.webpackJsonp.169.SignupPage.passwordValidat (signup.ts:71)
>       at forms.js:759

Comment: Well that means one of your `control.get()` calls is returning `null` make sure you are calling that function correctly and at the right time.

Comment: @DudeCoder chatty comments should be avoided they detract from the question and clutter the comment section... SO provides chatrooms https://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Patrick Evans , while debugging the issue at different time and senario getting the same error control.get() always returning null value.Could you please tell me a right way to do this password validation.and may i know 'what i did wrong?'

Comment: I added an answer in order to give you a hint how to figure out what the problem might be. You‘ll now see which password is null and if one of them is null, there won‘t be a crash any more but the program returning the invalid-object. — Use the console of your browser to monitor what‘s happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
passwordValidat(control: AbstractControl) {
    const  pwd = control.get('password');
    const cpwd = control.get('cpassword');

    console.log('pwd: ', pwd);
    console.log('cpwd: ', cpwd);

    if(pwd && cpwd) {

          if( pwd.value === cpwd.value ) {
              return { invalid: true };
          }
              return { validUrl: true };
          }

    } else {
        return { invalid: true };
    }

}
```